# Weighting co-occurrences with keyword frequency

Tags: r

I have got two data frames in R. The first one lists a certain number of keywords and their frequency (number of times detected in the text). The second data frame shows the co-occurrence of the key words (e.g. when two key words appear in the same chapter). I would like to create an additional column to my data which I will then use as weight. This third column ("w") would be based on w_(x1,x2) = co-occurrences / (number of times x1 is listed as a keyword + number of times x2 is listed as a keyword). Any idea how I should do it?

```
Key words    Frequency
art          5
risk         3
trade        1

X1    X2    w_(x1,x2)
art   risk  0.125
art   trade 0.1666667
```

Got this code but doesn't work and I'm still an amateur. Maybe there's something easier?

```
e <- df[,"keywords"]$`keywords`%>% 
str_split("\r\r\n") %>% 
lapply(function(x){expand.grid(x, x, w = (1 / length(x) + length(x)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)}) %>% 
bind_rows 

e <- apply(e[, -3], 1, str_sort) %>% 
t %>% 
data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
mutate(w = e$w)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation can be performed using the popular `tidyverse` package. Based on your comments, the problem quite straightforward.

```
    word_freq <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors =  FALSE,
                  text =    "Key_words    Frequency
                              art          5
                              risk         3
                              trade        1")

    co_occur <-   read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors =  FALSE,
              text ="X1    X2         w
                    art  risk 0.1250000
                    art trade 0.1666667")
    library(tidyverse)
#
#  Get the frequencies for each of X1 and X2, sum, and then compute the new weight
#   
    chapt_occur <- co_occur %>% left_join(word_freq, by = c(X1 = "Key_words")) %>% 
                                left_join(word_freq, c(X2 = "Key_words"), suffix = c(".X1", ".X2"))  %>%
                                mutate(comb_freq = Frequency.X1+Frequency.X2,
                                      w_X1X2 = w/comb_freq)
```

which gives the result

```
chapt_occur
  X1    X2         w Frequency.X1 Frequency.X2 comb_freq     w_X1X2
 art  risk 0.1250000            5            3         8 0.01562500
 art trade 0.1666667            5            1         6 0.02777778
```

The columns containing the intermediate calculations can be removed by using

```
 chapt_occur <- chapt_occur %>% select( -c(Frequency.X1, Frequency.X2, comb_freq))
```

This uses only basic tidyverse functions.  You can learn more about `tidyverse` many places including the online book by several of the developers [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Comment: Thank you for your insight! How do you do the weighing exactly? I would want to use a method following that line: co-occurrences / (number of times x1 is listed as a keyword + number of times x2 is listed as a keyword). The frequency is in another data frame (named "A"), so not sure how you can extract it. I've tried to use the ifelse function but not working: df1 <- data.frame(e$X1, e$X2)
df1$w <- if_else((df1$e.X1==A$Keywords & df1$e.X2==A$Keywords), A$Frequency, 0). Especially since it's a co-occurrence, I need each row to use only the frequency of the two words that are in common

Comment: OK.  You're saying that the co-occurance data frame should be used as an input  and combined with the word frequencies.  I've posted a revised solution but I'm still not clear on your calculation.

Comment: Yes exactly! I want my word frequency data frame to be used in my co-occurrence data frame. For each co-occurrence (e.g. art-risk), I only want the frequency of those two exact words to be counted (5 + 3 for example). How do you combine the frequency of all pairs into a third column  in the co-occurrence data frame by using the word frequency of the other data frame? Basically: how did you get your comb_freq? :) However my data frame is conditional, I do not want all possible pairs but only the existing ones. e.g. art-art does not exist in my data frame.

Comment: OK.  This version of the code seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you so much!